# java count the lines in a file and be able to read them later

Tags: java, file

I am trying to count the lines in a file to set a specified loop duration so that I can read the lines in the same file to extract the data.

I have tried do-while loops and while loops and the mistake that I keep seeing is that the program reads a line and then when I need the data from that line it reads the next line instead

```
...
while(in.readLine() != null){
    name = in.readLine();
    if (name != null && name.contains("Name: ")){
        name=name.substring(6);
        type = in.readLine();
        ...
```

Comment: Can you give us some more information? Maybe some more of the Java code? You gave us just a little snippet of it that's hardly enough to replicate your problem. What does your text file look like?

Comment: essentially that is the main coding issue the text file has one line after the other with different bits of data that pertain to an array that I need to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java will read the next line from the file every time you call `readLine()`. You only want to call it one time in the loop and store the value that's returned.

```
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)...
    // use line inside the loop instead of calling readLine() again
```

Comment: ok I had forgotten that the compiler can look at a line in a sort of "order of operations" way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's going to the next line of data when you need it is because you are gathering two lines per iteration of the loop. A simple change should get it working!

```
...
while((name = in.readLine()) != null){

if (name != null && name.contains("Name: ")){
    name=name.substring(6);
    type = in.readLine();
    ...
```